# SelectCommand.Connection is not initialized

Tags: c#, .net, sql, connection-string, sqldatareader

I'm trying to access my database, from this method in my DataBaseOptions class. I'm using this with ASP.NET for web development.

Whenever I run this method, In another class, I get following error:

> SelectCommand.Connection is not initialized

And it says that the error is on line 40. Here's my code:

(The line with "adapter.Fill(dt);" is line 40.

```
private string connectionString = "oop_string"; // Global Variable
private static SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(); // Global Variable
private static SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(); // Global Variable

public void setupConnection() {
    mycon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString].ToString();
    mycmd.Connection = mycon;
}

public bool UserExists(string username, string password) {
    setupConnection();

    mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username = @username AND user_password = @password";
    mycmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
    mycmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mycmd);

    adapter.Fill(dt);

    if(dt.Rows.Count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public int getUserID(string username, string password) {
        setupConnection();

        mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_username = @username AND user_password = @password";
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

        SqlDataReader reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(reader.Read()) {
            return Convert.ToInt32(reader["user_id"]);
        }

        mycon.Close();
        return 0;
}
```

If i try to put everything from setupConnection(); to the start of UserExists(); and getUserID(); I get the following error:

> ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Which it now claims, that the error is on line 51. The "SqlDataReader reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();".

My teacher and I, have tried everything, google, other classmates, teachers. We can't seen to find a solution.

Comment: Make sure you add mycon.Open in setupConnection() method and Add following line adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = mycon before  adapter.Fill(dt);. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You are **not opening the connection** anywhere in your code. Also consider ecnlosing your command and those object which implements IDisposable inside a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement

Comment: Where should the opening be? I can't seem to find the spot for it. Also, by adding this, I get an error saying 'ConnectionString' can't be editied. The Connection is open.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen, you should open the connection as late as possible and close it as early as possible. For your current structure you can open the connection after setting the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the connection

```
    public void setupConnection() {
    mycon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionString].ToString();
    mycon.Open()
    mycmd.Connection = mycon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give connection object while executing query which you have not given.

It is as follows:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mycmd,mycon);
```